# Output distinct element from array and its data from other associated arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

What is the best way to output data like this? I feel an example will explain far better than words.

If I have data like this

```
Array1 Array2 Array3 Array4

A      0      10     100

A      1      11     101

C      2      12     102

B      3      13     103

A      4      14     104

C      5      15     105

B      6      16     106

C      7      17     107

C      8      18     108

B      9      19     109
```

And I want it to output to file

File A

```
0 10 100

1 11 101

4 14 104
```

File B

```
3 13 103

6 16 106

9 19 109
```

File C

```
2 12 102

5 15 105

7 17 107

8 18 108
```

There can be an arbituary number of distinct elements in Array1. So if there are X distinct elements, I need to create X files.

The arrays are arrays of strings. They have the same number of elements.

I'll try to explain what I want to do in words: I want to select an array, in this case Array1, get all the distinct element in Array1, create a CSV file for every distinct element in Array1 with the name of the distinct element as the file name, and inside the file include all the data from the other arrays.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What types your arrays have? Do they have same number of elements?

Comment: You should use a class with meaningful properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier with either an array of proper structures, or with a multi-dimensional array, but with what you have...

You can "zip" the arrays

```
var bigArray = Array1.Zip(Array2, (a1, a2) => new {a1, a2})
                     .Zip(Array3, (a12, a3) => new {a12.a1, a12.a2, a3})
                     .Zip(Array4, (a123, a4) => new {a123.a1, a123.a2, a123.a3, a4})
```

then group by the value in the first array:

```
var query = bigArray.GroupBy(a => a.a1);
```

then "output" in a loop:

```
foreach(var file in query)
{
     Console.WriteLine("File {0}", file.Key);
     foreach(var item in file)
         Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", item.a2, item.a3, item.a4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have four arrays and each array have exactly same number of elements:

```
string[] Array1;
string[] Array2;
string[] Array3;
string[] Array4;
```

First step will be creation of anonymous types from your arrays and then grouping objects by value from first array:

```
var query = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, Array1.Length)
            select new {
                FileName = Array1[i],
                Value1 = Array2[i],
                Value2 = Array3[i],
                Value3 = Array4[i]
            } into x
            group x by x.FileName into g
            select g;
```

With this query you can save data to files:

```
foreach(var group in query)
{
   using (var writer = File.CreateText(group.FileName))
   {
       foreach(var item in group)
            writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
                             item.Value1, item.Value2, item.Value3));
   }
}
```

NOTE: If you have related data - e.g. second item in Array1 is related to second item in Array2 and both are related to second item in Array3, then it's better have single array of data structures which will hold all related items together. And of course, give valuable names for your variables.

Comment: How would I adapt your solution if I have an arbitrary number of arrays?

Comment: @user3240815 how do you get those arrays? Do you have variables for each array?

Comment: I read in a CSV file, read in a line, and use .Split(',') to get all the column names in an array. I am given an array that tells me which columns to include in the output. Then I use a nested for loop to find the positions of where the selected columns are and store it in a list of int. 

For example, if the columns are A, B, C, D, E, and I only want A, C, E, then my list would have "0", "2", "4". Then I make an array of list of strings of size "length of the list of int above", which is 3, then parse the info from the CSV into the array of list of strings

Comment: @user3240815 I would suggest to parse CSV lines directly into strongly typed objects. Btw where you get array that tells which columns to include in the output?

Comment: The array that tells me which columns to include in the output is a parameter given to this program. Do you know of a link that tells me what strongly typed objects are and how I might be able to utilize this for my program? Many thanks for all your help so far

Comment: @user3240815 strongly-typed objects are classes and structs. How do you know which column contain file name?